# Brother MFC-J825DW on WiFi network receiving print queue but not printing

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10, printing, brother

My Brother printer is not printing from my Laptop with Kubuntu 15.10 installed. When I tried printing a test page, the printer shows in settings 'Data file sent successfully'. The printer screen shows processing for a brief second and then did nothing.
My connection configuration is:

```
lpd://192.xxx.x.xx/mfcj825dw
```

and the driver shows "Current - Local Raw Printer".

I installed the drivers via [the Brother driver support page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj825dw_all&os=128). I used the "Driver Install Tool". I followed the instructions provided by brother. When the installer gave me options to select the destination Device URI, I chose "specify IP address". After entering the IP address, it defaulted to:

```
lpadmin -p MFCJ825DW -v socket://192.xxx.x.xx -E
```

of which I changed to the above because it was not responding at all.

What can I do to get the printer to work fully?

Would this contribute to the problem at all?

```
dpkg -i --force-all mfcj825dwlpr-3.0.1-1a.i386.deb
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
dpkg -i --force-all mfcj825dwcupswrapper-3.0.0-1a.i386.deb
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
###############################ls: cannot access /usr/share/ppd/*.ppd: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1):

[This site has complete instructions](https://sites.google.com./site/easylinuxtipsproject/15) on how to set up any brother printer. Quoting, with some formatting adaptation:

> Installing the driver manually isn't very difficult either, because
>   Brother has issued a generic install script for that: the Driver
>   Install Tool.
>
> With that, you can install not only the printer driver, but also (for
>   a multifunctional printer) the scanner driver.
>
> You can use it as follows:
>
> 1. Go to the download section of the Brother website and look up your printer model.
>
>    - For "OS Family" you choose Linux.
>    - For "OS Version" you select Linux (deb).
>    - Click the Search button.
>
>    Then click the Driver Install Tool and download
>      linux-brprinter-installer.
>
>    Save the downloaded file in the folder Downloads. Don't extract the
>      zipped file, but leave it there just as it is. Note: don't use the
>      installation how-to on the Brother website, but use the installation
>      how-to on my website instead (see below)!
> 2. Launch a terminal window.  (You can launch a terminal window like this: *Click*)
> 3. Now copy/paste the following command into the terminal, in order to unzip the downloaded file:
>
>    ```
>    cd Downloads && gunzip -v ~/Downloads/linux-brprinter*
>    ```
>
>    Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 4. Use copy/paste to transfer the following line to the terminal:
>
>    ```
>    sudo bash ~/Downloads/linux-brprinter*
>    ```
>
>    Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Type your password when prompted; this will
>      remain entirely invisible, not even asterisks will show, which is
>      normal.
> 5. Follow the steps that the installer script presents you. When asked for the printer model name, type it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    An example is best: for a Brother DCP-7065DN you type:
>
>    ```
>    DCP-7065DN
>    ```
>
>    Note: is there at the end of the model name a letter between
>      brackets? Then you probably have to omit that letter (including the
>      brackets).
>
>    Example: for the Brother MFC-L9550CDW(T) it becomes:
>
>    ```
>    MFC-L9550CDW
>    ```
>
>    At the question about the Device URI, you answer `N` for a USB
>      printer and `Y` for a network printer.
>
>    For a network printer, you select in the next question the last
>      option: (A): Auto. For that, you type the number of that option and
>      you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 6. Reboot your computer.
> 7. Done! Your printer should work fine now, including the scanner part (when present).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.